# Python: Dynamically create class while providing arguments to __init_subclass__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, metaprogramming, metaclass

How can I dynamically create a subclass of my class and provide arguments to its `__init_subclass__()` method?

Example class:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, my_name):
        print(f"Subclass created and my name is {my_name}")
```

Normally I'd implement my subclass as such:

```py
class MySubclass(MyClass, my_name="Ellis"):
    pass
```

But how would I pass in `my_name` when dynamically creating a subclass of `MyClass` using a metaclass? Normally I could use `type()` but it doesn't have the option of providing `my_name`.

```py
MyDynamicSubclass = type("MyDynamicSubclass", (MyClass,), {})
```

Comment: `type` is a metaclass. If you want to use a different metaclass, call that instead. The interface should be similar.

Comment: So, according to the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) `type` doesn't receive the argument. You would have to manually call it after the creation

Comment: Oh, so just use `MyDynamicSubclass.__init_subclass__(my_name="Ellis")`?

Comment: What happens if you pass the keyword arguments to `type` at the end of the argument list? The documentation implies that it's worth trying :)

Comment: E.g. `MyDynamicSubclass = type("MyDynamicSubclass", (MyClass,), {}, my_name='Ellis')`

Comment: @EllisPercival yes, I think you have to do it that way

Comment: @MadPhysicist oh! That totally worked!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object is what implies it would, in the first sentences of the section. I'll post an answer shortly

Comment: @MadPhysicist yep, I missed that

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Done

Comment: @EllisPercival. Thank you for an interesting question. It's been a while since I've looked into metaclasses and class creation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you're welcome! I doubt this will be the last time I get confused by metaclasses xD

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic documentation for [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) does not mention that it accepts an unlimited number of keyword-only arguments, which you would supply through the keywords in a `class` statement. The only place this is hinted in is in the Data Model in the section [Creating the class object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object):

> Once the class namespace has been populated by executing the class body, the class object is created by calling `metaclass(name, bases, namespace, **kwds)` (the additional keywords passed here are the same as those passed to `__prepare__`).

Normally, you would not use this feature with `type` exactly because of [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__):

> The default implementation `object.__init_subclass__` does nothing, but raises an error if it is called with any arguments.

Since you have overriden the default implementation, you can create your dynamic class as

```
MyDynamicSubclass = type("MyDynamicSubclass", (MyClass,), {}, my_name="Ellis")
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I didn't consider that the docs might omit that information. That works perfectly :)

Comment: @EllisPercival. They don't omit it as such. They just don't emphasize it. But I agree that they could be more explicit.